# What format is the output of LiDAR Ouster 1-16

Tags: format

Please tell me what format the output data from LiDAR Ouster 1-16?  I know that the .las format is used to store a cloud of laser point data, is this also true for this model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, LAS point cloud data is georeferenced data (in different coordinate systems, often a UTM coordinate system), whereas the Ouster (along with many other LIDARs) outputs data in the sensor coordinate system. Converting between these two is non-trivial and requires exact knowledge of the sensor location and orientation.

The specific output format for the OSx family of sensors is specified [here](https://data.ouster.io/downloads/software-user-guide-v1.13.0.pdf).